# Differentiablility of $f(x)=x^m\sin(1/x^n)$

Tags: calculus

[image]

My attempt:

I have to choose one from option A and option D. Option B can be eliminated by taking $m=1, n=2$. option C can also be eliminated by taking $m=4, n=3$.  Please help me to choose one from A and D.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

$f'(x)=mx^{m-1}sin(1/x^n)-nx^{m-n-1}cos(1/x^n)$ (for $x \neq 0$). The sine and cosine function are continuous; therefore differentiability arises if there are factors $x^a$ with $a \geq 0$. Otherwise the derivative of $f(x)$ would have a jump at $x=0$.

Comment: which option seems correct then?

Comment: A and D, because (A): $x^{m-n-1}=x^q$ with $q>0$ and for $m=1$ it must hold (strict inequality!) $n=0$, the 2nd term vanishes.

Comment: but only one of them is correct.

Comment: (D) is not correct; Ex.: m=0,n=1: first term vanishes and second has the factor $x^0$.

Comment: [The other answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1175530) is correct, this one is not . The OP's question was not "when is $f$ $C^1$ at $0$?" but "when is $f$ *differentiable* at $0$?" The formula for $f'(x)$ when $x\ne0$ is irrelevant for that question.

Answer (score 4):

I'll assume $n\ge1$, otherwise the problem is trivial.

Use the definition of derivative: the derivative exists if and only if
$$
f'(0)=\lim_{x\to 0}x^{m-1}\sin\frac{1}{x^n}
$$
exists and is finite.

If $m>1$, this limit exists and is zero, because, for $x\ne0$,
$$
-|x^{m-1}|\le x^{m-1}\sin\frac{1}{x^n}\le |x^{m-1}|
$$
and the squeeze theorem applies, so $f'(0)=0$. If $m\le1$ the limit does not exist.

No hypothesis whatsoever is needed on $n$. So, with this interpretation, A and D are true.

---

The case would be much different if the question is “does the function have continuous derivative at $0$?” But “differentiable at $0$” usually means “the function has a derivative at $0$”.

If continuous differentiability is required, then we know that $m>1$ and $f'(0)=0$, in this case. Moreover, for $x\ne0$,
$$
f'(x)=mx^{m-1}\sin\frac{1}{x^n}-nx^{m-n-1}\cos\frac{1}{x^n}
$$
and this is continuous everywhere, except possibly at $0$.

The limit of this function at $0$ should be $0$. Since $m>1$, we already know that
$$
\lim_{x\to0}x^{m-1}\sin\frac{1}{x^n}=0
$$
so we also need that
$$
\lim_{x\to0}x^{m-n-1}\cos\frac{1}{x^n}=0
$$
Note that if $m-n-1\le0$, the limit doesn't exist. Instead, if $m-n-1>0$, the limit is $0$ with the same argument as before.

So the condition for continuous differentiability at $0$ is $m>n+1$.

For example, if $m=2$ and $n=1$, the derivative is
$$
f'(x)=\begin{cases}
2x\sin\dfrac{1}{x}-\cos\dfrac{1}{x} & \text{if $x\ne0$}\\
0 & \text{if $x=0$}
\end{cases}
$$
and this function is not continuous at $0$.

So, if we consider this as the question, we have to choose non differentiability, so either C or D.

Comment: is A correct or D?

Comment: @ketan If $m>1$ then the function is differentiable at $0$. Suppose $m>n>0$: then $m>1$ and the function is differentiable at $0$; on the other hand, if $n=0$ the function is differentiable. Hence A is correct. But also D is correct, because for $m=1$ and $n>1$ the function is not differentiable at $0$.

Comment: So (to make sure and improve my english): D must be interpreted as "not [diff for each m<n]" and not as "[not diff] for each m<n"?

Comment: @egreg the condition for $m,n$ is already given that they belongs to natural numbers so further assumption for them to be greater than $0$ is not needed. So that makes option **d** also true, but official answer key to that question says only a option is correct [check question 28 ](https://www.iitr.ac.in/gate/papers/JAM2015/JAM2015_MA.pdf?download_file=papers/JAM2015/JAM2015_MA.pdf ) [ answer key](https://coap.iitm.ac.in/ajith/pdfs/MA_Key.pdf)

Comment: @DeepakKumar (context=my previous comment) Interpreting rather D as "[not diff] for each m<n" makes it false, which agrees with your answer key.

Comment: Yes, that makes sense. Thankyou ✨