# Finding Constants for Continuity

Tags: real-analysis

Given the function $ f(x) = x^a\sin(\frac{1}{x^b})$ if $x \ne 0,$ $0$ when $x=0$
for which values of $a,b$ is $f'(x)$ continuous at $0$?

So the derivative is $f'(x)=ax^{a-1}\sin(\frac{1}{x^b})-bx^{a-b-1}\cos(\frac{1}{x^b})$.

Is this continuous for all $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ at $x=0$? Since this is one of those oscillating functions, or because $f(x)$ is differentiable at $x=0$ only for $a > 2$, is that not true?

Comment: Why won't you first evaluate $\;f'(0)\;$ for whatever values of $\;a,b\;$ it exists?

Comment: Check the link: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1175500/differentiablility-of-fx-xm-sin1-xn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I used the definition of differentiability to see where the limit $f'(0)$ exists, and is therefore continuous.

for $f'(0) = lim_{x->0} \ ax^{a-1}sin(\frac{1}{x^b})=0$ when $a-1 > 0, $ so $a>1$. b should be able to be any real number.

and $f'(0) = lim_{x->0} \ bx^{a-b-1}cos(\frac{1}{x^b})=0$
when $a-b-1 >0$ and doesn't exist otherwise.